# How tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell points to tf.python.ops.rnn_cell_impl.LSTMCell?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am learning tensorflow and python packaging, and I wondering what happened under the hood when doing

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell
```

The implementation of LSTMCell locates at `tf.python.ops.rnn_cell_impl.LSTMCell` instead of `tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell`.

Is it because `tf.contrib.rnn.__init__` imports `tf.python.ops.rnn_cell.*`, which imports `rnn_cell_impl.LSTMCell`? Or it's something totally different?  Thanks

Comment: Which Tensorflow version are you using?

Comment: I'm using tensorflow 1.2 and python 3.5.  thanks